# Column width changes in HTML table if the table only has a single row

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a 1D array of objects. I need to display data from that array in a table with 3 columns.
I assign `1/3rd of 100% width` for each column, since number of columns is fixed.
If I have 3 or more objects to display, everything works fine. However if I have 1 or 2 objects then the column width changes, the columns expand to fit max width.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rzg4yh?file=index.js) is my code. I know there's inline css everywhere, it is on purpose. Please bear with me. I have provided an array with 2 objects and another with 4 objects so you can se the difference.
I know I can write a separate condition for no. of objects less than 3, and then set specific width, but I'm hoping this can be solved with CSS alone.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help out.

Edit: I have a JS based solution already. I calculate table width dynamically if array has less than 3 objects, like below.

```
let width = '100%';
if (listOfPeople.length < 3 && listOfPeople.length > 0) {
  width = (listOfPeople.length * 100) / 3 + '%';
}
```

And that width is used as so

```js
appDiv.innerHTML = `
    <table width="${width}" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <td style="width: calc(100% / 3); height: 100%; max-width: calc(100% / 3); padding: 10px;">
              data
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  `;
```

I have not updated this solution in the linked code as I was really hoping for a CSS solution. If anyone has any ideas then please let me kno

Comment: Never post links to code, code is text, and should be treated as such. Please post your code so that we can view it :)

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 variables here. `iterator` which just figures out how many TD's to make for any given row based on the remaining listOfPeople, and `perc` which figures out how wide to make the rows.

```js
const array2 = [
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'jhvjb']
  ]),
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich2'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'frds']
  ]),
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich2'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'frds']
  ]),
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich2'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'frds']
  ])
];


const array3 = [
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'jhvjb']
  ]),
  new Map([
    ['name', 'Jacqueline M. Goodrich2'],
    ['img', ''],
    ['department', 'Marketing'],
    ['location', 'frds']
  ])
]

function doTable(listOfPeople) {
  let cardsrows = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length;) {
    let cards = '';
    let iterator = Math.min((listOfPeople.length - i), 3)
    let perc = Math.min(listOfPeople.length, 3)
    for (let col = 0; col < iterator; col++) {
      const record = listOfPeople[i];
      const card =
        `<td style="border:1px solid #ccc; width: calc(100% / ${perc}); height: 100%; max-width: calc(100% / ${perc}); padding: 10px;">info</td>`;

      cards = cards.concat(card);
      i++;
    }


    const row = cards ? `<tr>` + cards + `</tr>` : ``;
    cardsrows = cardsrows.concat(row);
  }
  document.getElementById('appDiv').innerHTML = `
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            ${cardsrows}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  `;

}
```

```html
<div id='appDiv'></div>

<button onclick='doTable(array2)'>Table for 4</button> &nbsp;
<button onclick='doTable(array3)'>Table for 2</button>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Setting width on `td`  is not working.

Comment: @Amruta there is no table-layout reset in your style for table to give a chance to calculate anything, unless you use vw units to start from you may have a result. If table-layout is not reset to fixed, then width of table/td will be at least the width of its content. this is the table/display:table layout behavior. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ufba8d?file=style.css

Comment: @Amruta - please check out my revised answer with snippet. It should be what you're looking for...

Comment: @Amruta - does it solve the question? If so, please mark it as the answer. Thx.

Comment: @Kinglish Not this exact solution. I calculated table width dynamically too. 
`if (listOfPeople.length < 3 && listOfPeople.length > 0) {
  width = (listOfPeople.length * 100) / 3 + '%';
}`
 and then 
document.getElementById('appDiv').innerHTML = `
    <table width="${width}" border="0">
        <tbody>
            ${cardsrows}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  `;